# Generation of distinct vectors of dimension k with elements 1 and -1 in R

Tags: r

I want to compute a matrix (S) with k rows and 2^k column such that the following two conditions satisfied:

```
1) all of whose elements are either 1 or -1 ,
2) each column of S is a vector of dimension k and columns are distinct.
```

How to do this using R? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid`, which creates all combinations of input vectors:

```
k <- 3
t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1)), k)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#Var1    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1
#Var2    1    1   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1
#Var3    1    1    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to consider maximum possible unique column which is 2^k.

Comment: A column of  S represent a draw of k balls from an urn containing only white and red colour balls. So there are 2 ^k many distinct ways of doing this implying 2^k distinct columns. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution (recursive):

```
Mk <- function(k) {
  if (k==1) return(matrix(c(1,-1), 1, 2))
  cbind(rbind(1, Mk(k-1)), rbind(-1, Mk(k-1)))
}
Mk(3)
#> Mk(3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
#[2,]    1    1   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1
#[3,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1
```

Because of the recursion this solution is inefficient.
(But the recursion is so nice.)

```
library(microbenchmark)
k <- 3

Mk <- function(k) {
  if (k==1) return(matrix(c(1,-1), 1, 2))
  cbind(rbind(1, Mk(k-1)), rbind(-1, Mk(k-1)))
}

microbenchmark(
  expa=t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1)), k))),
  recu=Mk(k)
)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq     max neval
# expa 271.977 288.359 317.30903 294.872 326.254 871.983   100
# recu  41.449  45.001  53.24341  48.949  58.422 140.134   100
```

#### but:

```
k <- 10
microbenchmark(
  expa=t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1)), k))),
  recu=Mk(k)
)
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
# expa  853.430  873.562  978.7562 1001.26 1017.050 2551.999   100
# recu 6627.696 6706.249 7105.9993 6778.29 7079.082 9073.509   100
```

Comment: This is a nice educational example of recursion, but unfortunately inefficient in R (for large `k`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is taking a bit time.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I know.

Comment: @jogo, your solution reminds me a lot of the `combinations/permutations` algorithm in the `gtools` package.  Very nice usage of recursion!!

Answer (score 0):

When there are only 2 possible outcomes I think of bits.

```
OneOrMinusOne <- function(x, dig) {
    i <- 0L
    string <- numeric(dig)-1L
    while (x > 0) {
        string[dig - i] <- ifelse(x%%2L==0L,-1L,1L)
        x <- x %/% 2L
        i <- i + 1L
    }
    string
}

sapply(0:(2^3 - 1), function(x) OneOrMinusOne(x,3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1    1
[2,]   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1    1    1
[3,]   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1
```

Although this is very natural, it isn't nearly as efficient as using `expand.grid` as Roland did above.

## Update

This problem is very interesting because of how many ways you can think about it. I've already mentioned the connection with binary representations of numbers from 0 to (2<sup>n</sup> - 1), however, there are many more.

**1. Geometry** (Image was obtained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/281287))
[image]
The answer the OP is looking for when `k = 3` is precisely the coordinates of the vertices of a cube centered at the origin. For larger `k`, the answer is similar (i.e. the answer will be the coordinates of the vertices of `kth` dimensional [hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube)).  Mathematically, this can be described by the intersection of a hypersphere with radius `sqrt(k)` and hypercube with edges of length = 2, both of which are centered at the origin. For `k = 3` this would translate into the following equation:

*x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup> = 3*      where (x,y,z) are integral values (i.e. 1 or -1)

**2. Abstract Algebra**

We can think of the solution as [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism) to the [Multiplicative group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group) of integers modulo 2<sup>k + 1</sup>.  You may be wondering why the `k+1`. Well, it just so happens that [Euler's totient function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) gives us the order of these types of groups, thus we have:

phi(2<sup>k+1</sup>) = 2<sup>k+1</sup> * (1 - 1/2) = 2<sup>k</sup>

Each element is its own inverse, the element `rep(1, k)` serves as the identity, and it is closed under multiplication (element-wise multiplication (e.g. (1, -1, 1) * (-1, -1, 1) = (-1, 1, 1))).

If you really want to get crazy with Group theory, the solution set can be more thoroughly described as a [Coxeter Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group). This may actually be useful in efficiently generating the solution as you really only need a few vectors to fully describe the solution set. For example, for `k = 3`, starting only with 3 vectors, we can generate the entire solution set.

```
myL <- list(c(-1,-1,1),c(-1,1,-1),c(-1,1,1))  ## generating set
myL[[4]] <- myL[[1]]*myL[[2]]
myL[[5]] <- myL[[1]]*myL[[3]]
myL[[6]] <- myL[[1]]*myL[[2]]*myL[[3]]
myL[[7]] <- myL[[2]]*myL[[3]]
myL[[8]] <- myL[[1]]^2
do.call(cbind, myL)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   -1   -1   -1    1    1   -1    1    1
[2,]   -1    1    1   -1   -1   -1    1    1
[3,]    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1   -1    1
```

I haven't proved this, but with every example I've tried, the general solution for any `k` seems to be completely described by the set of `k` distinct vectors ((-1,1,...1), (1,-1,1,...,1), (1,1,-1,1,...,1),...,(1,...,1,-1)).

Anyway, this was a lot of fun.